# Dns.GetHostByAddress() works but Dns.GetHostEntry() doesn't

Tags: c#, .net

I changed my code so it no longer uses the deprectaed:

```
Dns.GetHostByAddress(ipaddress);
```

to use:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(ipaddress);
```

The problem is I get an exception from Dns.GetHostEntry

```
No such host is known

SOURCE: System

TARGETSITE: System.Net.IPHostEntry GetAddrInfo(System.String)
```

If I go back to the deprecated Dns.GetHostByAddress it correctly looks up the hostname from the IP address I give it.

I see this problem on XP 64bit and Windows 7. Haven't tried it on anything else. I'm using .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that Dns.GetHostEntry does a reverse lookup and Dns.GetHostByAddress doesn't.

Try other ip address / hostnames and you will see that sometimes it works.

I don't know of any solution, but maybe there is. You can stick with the obsolete function until you found a solution.

Comment: Actually Dns.GetHostByAddress() does a reverse lookup just fine for me. I give it 192.168.0.1 and it gives me back the corresponding hostname.

Comment: That's not what he means, try Dns.GetHostByName() and pass the hostname.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I want to get the hostname from an IP not the other way around.